# Mapbox Polyline Installation Image Not Found Error

Tags: ios, crash, mapbox, polyline

I tried to install Mapbox Directions and Navigation using Carthage including Mapbox Polyline.  After following the instructions which after using Carthage to compile the file, consisted of dragging the framework into embedded binaries (which also copies it into the linked libraries), although the Program compiles okay, when I ran it, it crashed with the exception:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Polyline.framework/Polyline
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F3EE3E01-2A3E-43B5-9629-AD5F251552EC/planner.app/planner
  Reason: image not found
```

I have now deleted the framework from both the embedded binaries and linked libraries and cleaned the project, but am still getting the identical error.

Grateful for any suggestions.